# URL generation in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am generating links to static HTML pages hosted on (local) shiny-server within an output table in a shiny app. Since the table is generated every time from user's search inputs, I am creating the links on the fly based on search results. The generated links include an addition to the path (changing with every session):  e.g. http://myServer.org/myApp/app095c75e71384b9d0dd0018637b10fa00/myStaticPage.html . Is it possible to generate a stable link that is fixed for all users and app sessions, ideally without meaningless strings in the middle?

This is the overall app layout with the code snippet I use to generate the link:

```
#server.R:

dt=read_csv("path/To/data.csv")

shinyServer <- function (input, output) {

 res.table=eventReactive(input$submit, {

  res=dt
  upVal=as.numeric(input$value)
  res=subset(res,res$val>value)
  return(res)

 }

 output$res=DT::renderDataTable({
  res=res.table()

   #processes the name string to extract the reference name in the HTML page
   toLink.fun=function(z){
     if (length(grep("/",z,fixed = T))>0) {
       splitz=strsplit(as.character(z),"/")
       zLink=splitz[[1]][2]
     } else {zLink=z}
     paste0("<a href='",zLink,"_info.html' target='_blank' >",z,"</a>",collapse  = "")
   }

   res[,1]=sapply(res[,1],toLink.fun)
   res=DT::datatable(res, escape=-2)

   return(res)
  })

}
```

and

```
#ui.R:

sidebarPanel(
 fluidRow(sliderInput("value", label="min value", min=10, max=1000, value="100")),
 fluidRow(actionButton(inputId="submit", label="submit"))
),

mainPanel(DT::dataTableOutput('res'))
```

Comment: Can you share your entire application's code?

I believe that we can find a solution, but I want to be sure that I'm seeing everything that you're working with. Thank you.

Comment: @kostr Apologies for the late reply, I had to momentarily pause working on this issue. Unfortunately, I cannot share the full app code, but I have edited to insert the main components. The app contains only some input panels for search filtering and outputs the table of results in the main panel. The rest of the code uses readr and dplyr .